# how to pass output of one web service as input to another web service

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I have written one web service which returns float value.
I want to display that float value by passing it as input to another web service.
How to pass the value from one web service to another?
I am using bottom up approach.

Comment: I guess same way you are calling the 1st web service.

Comment: I tried that. Written a method which takes float value. And call this method from previous method. But did not work.

Comment: public class Converter
{
  public void celsiusToFarenheit ( float celsius )
  {
   float no = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
   disply(no);
  }

  public void farenheitToCelsius ( float farenheit )
  {
   float no = (farenheit * 9 / 5) + 32;
   disply(no);
   
  }
  
  public float disply(float no)
  {  
   return no;
  }
}

Comment: created a web service for above code. When I click on display method it should print the value calculated by celsiusToFarenheit function. But it did not dispaly that vale. It accepts new value and prints it